# Backbone.js - Replace existing model in collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following collection:

```
UsersMod.users_list = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    add : function(model) {

        var duplicate = this.any(function(_model) { 

            return _model.get('user') === model.get('user');

        });

        if (duplicate) {

            return false;

        }

        Backbone.Collection.prototype.add.call(this, model);

    }

});
```

This currently checks for a duplicate model in the collection and returns false if one is found. What I'm trying to do is when a duplicate is found, remove the old one and replace it with the new one.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UsersMod.users_list = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    add : function(model) {

        var duplicates = this.filter(function(_model) { 

            return _model.get('user') === model.get('user');

        });

        if (! _(duplicates).isEmpty) {

            this.remove(duplicates);

        } 

        Backbone.Collection.prototype.add.call(this, model);

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, should "duplicates" be "duplicate" when you call "this.remove(duplicates)" ? Or more specifically, where is duplicates defined? Thanks again :)

Comment: Isn't `this.add(model);` referring to the method itself? as in `this.add === arguments.callee` Also, you'd probably want to pass in `{silent: true}` if no events are meant to be fired from replacements

Comment: Sorry for the typo on duplicates. Fixed. Also, the `this` here refers to the object on which add is called, the collection. `this.add` would add to the collection. Yes you'd want silent:true but chances are if the collection has a corresponding view, you'd want to trigger its re-rendering.

Comment: You also need to replace the last line with       Backbone.Collection.prototype.add.call(this, model); , if you are not a fan of infinite recursion :D

Comment: Oh man, I totally didn't put 2 and 2 together and realize the method being defined was called "add." Disregard what I said about `Backbone.Collection.prototype.add.call(this, model)` and use that instead of `this.add`

Comment: I would suggest though that you not override add like this and, instead, call the method something like add_without_dups. Then you can do `this.add`